# Is EEPROM persisted across program flashes?

Tags: eeprom

If I use `EEPROM.write(someAddr, someValue)` to write a value to an address, how long will that value "stick" to that address before being lost?

If I were to power down the Arduino, flash a whole new program to it, and power it on, could I still retrieve that old/cached value written from the previous program?

Comment: I am also interested in a technical answer to your first paragraph. Do you not have an Arduino to perform the test in the second paragraph yourself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only if the `EESAVE` fuse is programmed (it is unprogrammed by default). If not then the EEPROM will be erased when a chip erase command is performed.

Comment: Do you know how the Arduino IDE handles this? There are zero user options there.

Comment: @JorisGroosman: It doesn't. You'll need to use avrdude and ISP in order to read or manipulate the fuses.

Comment: So the IDE erases the EEPROM? I would say this explicitly in your answer, it seems important.

Comment: @JorisGroosman: It erases the EEPROM if the `EESAVE` fuse isn't programmed.

Comment: Yes, that's what you said. But I understand the `EESAVE` fuse is not set by default(?), and many users will just use the IDE, not avrdude.

Comment: @JorisGroosman You have to use `avrdude` to program the fuse.  Once you have done that, the IDE won't erase EEPROM.

Comment: I have couple of Unos, all of them keep eeprom content betweem flashing and I did not do anything with fuses.

Comment: It has been a while but I believe one of my Arduino projects that reads/writes EEPROM behaved as Michal Foksa explains.

Answer (score 0):

> how long will that value "stick" to that address before being lost?

The Atmega328 data retention is guaranteed by Atmel (the manufacturer) for 20 years at 85 degrees Celsius, 100 years at 25 degrees Celsius. Beware cheap Chinese clones usually use counterfeits chips, meaning those values are not going to be guaranteed any more

> If I were to power down the Arduino, flash a whole new program to it, and power it on, could I still retrieve that old/cached value written from the previous program?

While @ignacio answer is more detailed I believe you are interested in plain Arduino IDE programming along with standard Arduino boards, in which case the answer is **yes**, the data is not going to be erased.