# Arduino EEPROM retains old data after flashing with a new program

Tags: arduino-uno, avr, eeprom, flash

I have a custom 5V 16Mhz Arduino Uno (a breadboard Uno of sorts) that runs the grbl firmware. After the initial flashing I can see all the settings (through the serial monitor) and everything works. However, if I make any changes to the firmware files and re-flash it, I can see that the old settings values have not been replaced with the new ones. I can only assume that these values are in the EEPROM and are not being erased on every re-flash cycle. I then tried the `eeprom_clear` program from Examples in the Arduino IDE and then re-flashed with the new firmware settings, after which I can see the new settings values.

I did some [digging](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/11846/is-eeprom-persisted-across-program-flashes) and found that the EESAVE fuse is responsible for this. However the Uno does have this fuse bit unprogrammed (set to 1). Why then am I able to see the old EEPROM settings and have to explicitly run an eeprom clear program before re-flashing with the updated firmware?

Comment: I'm pretty sure Arduino IDE isn't uploading eeprom at all. And for example in Platform IO CLI, there is different command to upload eeprom data instead of flashing program memory.

Comment: The IDE isn't. The program is setting values in the EEPROM. I simply want to clear the EEPROM everytime a new program is uploaded.

Comment: Also posted at http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=469061

Comment: save the old built date to eeprom and on boot, if it's different than the current build, run your clear routine

Answer (score 2):

Flash isn't EEPROM. When you reprogram the flash it doesn't touch the EEPROM.

It's controlled by the `-U...` flag to `avrdude`:

```
avrdude ... -Uflash:w:<hex file>
```

If you want to set the EEPROM to something specific you can use `avrdude` to program an EEPROM file if the bootloader supports it (not sure it does, so you may need a programmer for it):

```
avrdude ... -Ueeprom:w:<hex file>
```

Comment: I do not want to program the EEPROM. I simply want to clear its contents whenever I re-flash the Uno with a new program. When you burn the Arduino bootloader this bit remains unchanged and hence whenever the IDE runs `avrdude` with an `-e` parameter it erases the flash and the eeprom. Am I right? If so, this does not seem to be the case with my Uno and I'm hoping to understand why.

Comment: It's all to do with what the bootloader is capable of. You're not programming the board, you're uploading firmware for the board to program itself - it's a very different scenario.

Comment: You could add a "reset to factory settings" button - if it's held in while the power is turned on (or the board reset, or programmed, etc) it wipes the EEPROM.

Answer (score 1):

The -e parameter in avrdude should only erase the EEPROM if the fuse bit

Preserve EEPROM memory through the Chip Erase cycle; [EESAVE=0]

is not set. However it appears it is not possible to SET this fuse bit. (at least not with AVRDUDESS.